# GitHub Action that updates the workflow file of another Action

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two GitHub Actions in the same repo. I'm trying to update one from the other, but I get the following error when trying to commit and push the changes:

`! [remote rejected] HEAD -> some-branch (refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow .github/workflows/the-other-action.yml without workflows permission)`

This is a simplified version of the GH Action I'm trying to run:

```
name: my-action

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 9 * * *"

jobs:
  components:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Update the other Action
        run: |
          # Do something to .github/workflows/the-other-action.yaml here

      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3
        with:
            token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            branch: some-branch
            commit-message: Updated stuff
```

I'm trying to figure out how to give the `workflows` permission to the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, but not sure how to?

(For context: I'm running this action once per day to check if a new version of a tool used in the other action has been released. If so, it creates a PR updating the other action to use the newer version instead)

Comment: You would need to use a [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) with workflows permission here, instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` which has a defined scope. Is this `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` your PAT? If it is, there is a problem, because [you can't add secrets with the `GITHUB_` prefix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#naming-your-secrets).

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd! `GITHUB_TOKEN` is the default token, not a PAT. But I ended up using a PAT as a workaround. Good to know that it isn't possible with the default token then.

Comment: Great! :D 
If this resolved your issue, can I add an official answer to your question?

Comment: @GuiFalourd, sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You need to use a Personal Access Token with workflows permission here, instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` which has a defined scope.

Actually, this just changed (Sept. 8th, 2022) with:

> ### [GitHub Actions: Use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` with `workflow_dispatch` and `repository_dispatch`](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-08-github-actions-use-github_token-with-workflow_dispatch-and-repository_dispatch/)
>
> Customers will now be able to use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` with `workflow_dispatch` and `repository_dispatch` events to trigger workflows.
>
> Prior to this change, events triggered by `GITHUB_TOKEN` would not create a new workflow run. This was done to prevent the accidental trigger of endless workflows.
>
> This update makes an exception for `workflow_dispatch` and `repository_dispatch` events since they are explicit calls made by the customer and not likely to end up in a loop.
>
> ```yaml
> name: Create Workflow Dispatch
>
> on:   workflow_dispatch:
>
> jobs:   build:
>     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>     steps:
>       - name: Trigger Workflow
>         uses: actions/github-script@v6
>         with:
>           script: |
>             github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch({
>               owner: context.repo.owner,
>               repo: context.repo.repo,
>               workflow_id: 'test.yml',
>               ref: 'main',
>             })
> ```
>
> For more details see
> **[Triggering a workflow from a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow)**.

So `GITHUB_TOKEN` might now work.

---

In the context of the OP's question: the primary task here is to modify a workflow file from within another workflow.

The recent GitHub change that I mention above allows for triggering workflows with the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, but it does not explicitly mention whether the token can be used to push changes to workflow files directly. That ability would solve the original issue.

You will still need to modify your workflow to commit and push the changes to the workflow file. The step in the action where you are trying to update the workflow file would look something like this:

```yaml
- name: Update the other Action
  run: |
    # Do something to .github/workflows/the-other-action.yaml here
    git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
    git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
    git add .github/workflows/the-other-action.yaml
    git commit -m "Update the other Action"
    git push
```

You need to use a token that has the necessary permissions to push the changes, and you can test it with the updated abilities of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`:

With the `peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3` action, that would be:

```yaml
- name: Create Pull Request
  uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    branch: some-branch
    commit-message: Updated stuff
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers OP's question though. It was how to modify a workflow file from a workflow, correct?

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst You are correct. I have edited the answer to better address the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) with **workflows permission** here, instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` which has a defined scope.

Moreover, if this `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` is your PAT, there might be a problem because [you can't add secrets with the GITHUB_ prefix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#naming-your-secrets). So you would have to rename the secret following this syntax.