# GitHub workflow failing all of a sudden as permission is missing. But why?

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I've a workflow on my repo that checks for updates every other day from the upstream and if the upstream has any updates i.e., new commits, my workflow will fetch updates from it and rebase my repo with my changes on top of it.

The workflow worked fine until yesterday morning with no issues. All of a sudden, the workflow now fails to update my repo with an error that states `workflows` permission is missing. Full error below:

```
![remote rejected]    main -> main (refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/diffuse.yml` without `workflows` permission)
```

I understand I need to give it the workflow permission but I've a question:
Why is this error even being thrown at me all of a sudden when I've neither created a `GitHub App` nor created a `PAT` and it was working fine without these.

YAML Code:

```yaml
      - name: Setup Git
        run: git config --global user.email ${{ secrets.EMAIL }} && git config --global user.name username

      - name: Fetch from Upstream
        run: |
          git remote add upstream https://github.com/upstream-repo/repo.git
          git fetch upstream --tags
          
          # Some extra code here

          if [ $has_new_commits == "true" ]; then
            git checkout main
            git rebase upstream/main || git diff
            git push -f origin main
            echo "Rebase successful!"
          else
            echo "ERROR: No commits to be synced!"
            exit 1
          fi

  build_app:
    needs: update_fork
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build.yml
    secrets: inherit
```

I did tried checking the repo and the settings to see whether I had previously created an App for it by mistake or not. No, I have NEVER created any app for this to give permission. At the repo level, every settings is as expected and intact.
I didn't even change the code to break.

Did GitHub do any changes in their backend that broke my workflow? How can I get my workflow running again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only very recent change (yesterday, June 16th 2023) regarding tokens is:

> ### [GitHub Actions – Securing OpenID Connect (OIDC) token permissions in reusable workflows](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-15-github-actions-securing-openid-connect-oidc-token-permissions-in-reusable-workflows) (Jun. 2023)
>
> For securely enabling OpenID Connect (OIDC) in your reusable workflows, we are now making the permissions more restrictive.
>
> If you need to fetch an OIDC token generated within a reusable (called) workflow that is outside your enterprise/organization, then the permissions setting for `id-token` should now be explicitly set to `write` at the caller workflow level or in the specific job that calls the reusable workflow.
>
> ```yaml
> permissions:
> id-token: write # This is required for requesting the JWT
> ```
>
> This change would ensure that the OIDC token generated in the called workflow is allowed to be consumed in the caller workflows only when intended.
>
> Learn more about [permission settings to enable OIDC in your workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-cloud-providers#adding-permissions-settings)

But I fail to see how it is related to your current error.

I reported myself the [last policy change in Sept. 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73654166/6309) which was relevant for this kind of error.

Your error was [reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66643917/6309), as you must have seen: a PAT with workflow permission, and used in the [`token` field of `actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage) should be enough for your action to work.
Nothing in [GitHub Status](https://www.githubstatus.com/) would explain this change, though.

---

As noted by the OP in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76496564/github-workflow-failing-all-of-a-sudden-as-permission-is-missing-but-why/76496646?noredirect=1#comment134879393_76496646)

> I fetched the latest update to my local again and started to inspect for `diffuse.yml` which is a file that never existed before and I believe, it is failing because of that.
>
> That diffuse.yml file was added by the upstream to monitor the file size changes and I now need to wait until they push another update to see whether that fixed that issue (I removed the file as I don't need it on my fork).

The addition of a GitHub workflow file would indeed explain why this permission level is now required.

Comment: I too don't understand like why this change affected me since I'm not using any kind of tokens to update the repo. However, I accidentally hooked upon my previous question that was raised in Jan of this year: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155070/cannot-force-push-to-main-branch-using-github-actions which had previously solved my issue and that solution is failing today.

Comment: @theycallmepix Strange indeed. And I do not see any [recent discussion on this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions?discussions_q=workflow).

Comment: I just tried giving write permission to actions and still that didn't help. Looks like they've made some specific change in the backend that is stopping me from using running my commands.

Comment: @theycallmepix I am frantically refreshing the [GitHub Incident page](https://www.githubstatus.com/history). So far, nothing...

Comment: The workflow started to fail since yesterday morning at around 10 AM. But I think I found the issue but unsure of how to test it as I updated my repo with the latest one. I fetched the latest update to my local again and started to inspect for `diffuse.yml` which is a file that never existed before and I believe, it is failing because of that. I removed the file and pushed it to my repo. I cannot revert back to previous version since it will remove my changes and it is destructive.

Comment: @theycallmepix Good point.  I have added your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Yea, thanks for updating. That `diffuse.yml` file was added by the upstream to monitor the file size changes and I now need to wait until they push another update to see whether that fixed that issue (I removed the file as I don't need it on my fork). I'll currently running out of time to: save the top commit to a branch, reset to previous release, put back my changes, push and run the workflow. I'll try to do it once I find some space or wait for upstream to push an update... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @theycallmepix Good catch. Let me know if you make it work. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that did work! So basically, I had 2 options, either to remove the workflow file since I don't need it, as I only build my modified of the application, or to add the `contents: write` permission to `diffuse.yml` to get the workflow working.